# Нужны ли пробелы до и после тире, которое стоит между буквами, для обозначения диапазона (рамок): А — Я / А—Я?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, дефис-тире, алфавит, буквы

Если на письме у нас есть диапазон букв, то что между ними ставится — тире с пробелами или тире без пробелов (или даже так называемое короткое тире)? Мне кажется, тире с отбивками, ведь этот случай подпадает под правило, когда ставится тире в значении "от X до Y" (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95)).

*Буквы А — Я, A — Z.*

*Взводы A — C выдвигаются на позиции; D — E прикрывают.* (Хотя D и E, вероятно, лучше через запятую — правильно подсказали, ведь между ними нет других букв.)

Однако я вроде бы видел где-то букварь, в котором для обозначения рамок между буквами почему-то стоял дефис (А-Я). Нет ли тут подвоха? Или это просто составители букваря ошиблись (либо мне показалось)?

"Грамота.ру" говорит, что ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ случай, когда тире не отбивается пробелами, — это позиция между **цифрами** (например, 1—2, 1941—1945), см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286781). Значит, к ситуации, когда у нас диапазон **букв**, это правило не относится и надо ставить тире с отбивками? Но есть ли точное указание? Может, у Мильчина найдётся рекомендация на сей счёт?

Comment: Уверен, что видел где-то буквари... /// Это повод найти словари. И в диапазоне «D — E» букв нет.

Comment: Может быть и такое, что речь там просто шла о парных гласных (А-Я, У-Ю), вот и не так понял. А почему букв нет в названиях взводов? Как-то не понял, что вы имеете в виду, это же буквами названы подразделения... В любом случае, как правильно-то? С тире с отбивками?

Comment: Названия взводов (в роте) различаются порядковым номером. Переходя на буквы, это надо учитывать: условные D и E означают 4 и 5 взводы. Тире между ними вместо союза *и*?

Comment: Тире тут в значении "от Х до Y", то есть взводы с A по C. А в случае D и E, действительно, они ведь в порядке рядом стоят, тут запятая или союз "и" тогда уместнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никто вопрос не отметил, и мне он поначалу тоже показался заурядным. Ан не так все элементарно оказалось, когда я просто порылась в поисках примеров.

Начала с того, что имеется.
Словообразовательный словарь русского языка в 2 томах. А. Н. Тихонов (1990 г.):
СЛОВОБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ГНЕЗДА. **Р — Я** (стр. 3).
Точно такое же оформление этого словаря (только 1985 года) нашлось в списке рекомендуемой литературы: [*А — П, Р — Я*](https://books.google.ee/books?id=63PVDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=%D0%A2.%202:%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0.%20%D0%A0%E2%80%94%D0%AF.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=CwLYPJWoJ2&sig=ACfU3U1QX8l0WHdQykmqcslPW_Y17mMTFQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbnK6r5eL4AhXNlYsKHT8gA584ChDoAXoECBIQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2.%202%3A%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0.%20%D0%A0%E2%80%94%D0%AF.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false) (Русский язык. Морфемика. Словообразование. Морфология. Наталия Лобачева).

А вот то, что нашлось в словарных "картинках".

Этимологический словарь русского языка М. Фасмера. Том 1. **А — Д**.
Этимологический словарь мирового русского языка. Том 4. [**С — Я**](https://ridero.ru/books/etimologicheskii_slovar_mirovogo_russkogo_yazyka/).
Орфографический словарь русского языка. **А-я**.
Словарь русского языка в 4 томах (1985). Том 1. [**А—Й**](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/books/original/25052/%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A1%20%D1%821.pdf).
Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный. Т. Ф. Ефремова. [**А—О**](https://allatra.club/post/novyj-slovar-russkogo-jazyka-tolkovoslovoobrazovatelnyj.html).
Словарь синонимов русского языка / Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой: В 2 т. Т. 1 (**А — Н**). Л., 1970; Т. 2 (**О — Я**). Л., 1971 ([Синонимические словари. Грамота](http://gramota.ru/slovari/types/17_13)).

Оказалось, что пишут-то по-разному, даже с дефисом с пробелами.
Еще раз перечитала Розенталя.
Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов ***пространственных*** (поезд Москва — Иркутск — Хабаровск — Владивосток), *временны́х, количественных.*
Да, нашего варианта нет в правилах.
А я бы его отнесла к пространственным пределам, предполагая, что внутренность книги можно назвать (представить) пространством книги, и написала бы *А — Я* с пробелами.

[«А — Я»](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/612338) (журнал неофициального русского искусства).
[А — Я](http://old.orlovka.org.ru/crimea_abc/) (Азбука «КРЫМ»).

Comment: Римма, спасибо за обстоятельный ответ! Я тоже склоняюсь к варианту с тире с пробелами. Так что по работе и награда:)

Comment: И я Вас благодарю за оценку и добрые слова (не кошка, конечно, но приятно).